# trying to send internet access check result to an activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a non-activity that check for internet access using async task. By the way, the code for internet access check works correctly in an activity. Now when I added the code to a non-activity class, I want the response to be saved into a string and send to MainActivity using "startActivityForResult". I added a Toast to check if the value is passing to the MainActivity, but Toast shows blank. So, either the response is not saving int the string or its not sending to MainActivity. I've also posted the log cat as when I button click in MainActivity due to value being null, the app crashes.

```js
LogCat

09-26 13:31:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(22041): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 13:31:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(22041): Process: com.example.networkping, PID: 22041
09-26 13:31:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(22041): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 13:31:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(22041):  at com.example.networkping.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:43)
09-26 13:31:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(22041):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4562)
09-26 13:31:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(22041):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18918)
09-26 13:31:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(22041):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
09-26 13:31:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(22041):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
09-26 13:31:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(22041):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
09-26 13:31:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(22041):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388)
09-26 13:31:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(22041):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 13:31:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(22041):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-26 13:31:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(22041):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-26 13:31:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(22041):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:655)
09-26 13:31:26.872: E/AndroidRuntime(22041):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

```css
Non-Activity AsyncTask class

 public  class Internet extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{
    
    String sam;
    Context context;
    Activity activity;
    
    public Internet(Activity ac) {
         activity = ac;
     }
    
    
    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
    
        @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
        if(result){
         
         // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         sam="1";
         Intent view = new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class);
         view.putExtra("zipcode", sam.toString());
         activity.startActivityForResult(view, 1);
        }
           
        
         
        else{
         
         // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         sam="0";
      Intent view = new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class);
      view.putExtra("zipcode", sam.toString());
      activity.startActivityForResult(view, 1);
         
        }
            
      }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
             if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                  try {
                   HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL( "http://www.google.com"    ).openConnection());
                      urlc.connect();
                      int resp = urlc.getResponseCode(); 
                      return resp == 200;
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                      //Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error checking internet connection", e);
                   System.out.println("Error checking internet connection"+e);
                  }
                } else {
                  //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "No network available!");
                 System.out.println("No network available!");
                }
                return false;
        }
    



 
 
   }
```

```html
MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 
    Button check;
    String zipcode;
  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     
     
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        zipcode = getIntent().getExtras().getString("zipcode");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), zipcode, 3000).show();

        check=(Button)findViewById(R.id.check);
  check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //new CheckInternetConnection().execute();
    //String zipcode = getIntent().getExtras().getString("zipcode");
    if(zipcode.equals("1")){
     
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
    }else if(zipcode.equals("0")){
     
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
    }
   }
  });

        
    }// oncreate


       } //activity
```

Comment: post your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
zipcode = getIntent().getStringExtra("zipcode");
```

instead of

```
zipcode = getIntent().getExtras().getString("zipcode");
```

Comment: still the same result. I think there is some fault in saving the string in Internet.java

Answer (score 0):

The simplest most efficient way to accomplish this is using **Events**. In android, like most other development environments, you always want to avoid coupling in your code - that means you want as much loose coupling as possible to avoid parts of your classes knowing too much about others.

So, using https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus library (highly popular and recommended), you can simply notify the activity of the internet connection status by posting a new Event as long as the activity subscribes to that event.

You then simply override an **onEvent(EventClassName event )** method to set your string variable accordingly.

I hope this helps - the documentation on how to use the above mentioned event library is pretty helpful on how to get started.

Good luck!